# asm.js - Get value of pointer

Tags: pointers, integer, emscripten, asm.js

Asm.js deals with a lot of math and for simplicity it uses ints as pointers.

I am trying to debug some code, but I can't see the actual values, only the 'pointers' in asm.js.

Is there any way to go straight to the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to the `Module` object, say in dev tools, and if you have the pointer value and know what type of variable it points to, you can use [`getValue`](http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html#access-memory-from-javascript). For example, to retrieve a 32 bit integer at memory location `2434`, you would call:

```
Module.getValue(2434, 'i32');
```

You can use `i8`, `i16`, `i32`, `i64`, `float` or `double` for the type of data at the memory location. I don't know if there are other types you can pass.

Comment: The getValue method works, but returns another memory address. As JF said it would compromise the security of the code if you would be afle to get the actual value.

Comment: @BerianuCVlad If getValue returns a memory address, you can pass that into getValue again to get the value at that location.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it uses ints isn't for simplicity it's for security: the code shouldn't be able to index outside of the ArrayBuffer: the heap you see has an extra indirection exactly the same way usespace can't see physical addresses and instead only sees virtual addresses (except asm.js doesn't fragment the underlying storage).

What are you trying to do?

If you're trying to get the value from a debugger then something may be possible (figure out the base address of the ArrayBuffer by using a breakpoint on its construction, add the index).

If you want the value from your C++ code that's compiled to asm.js then that won't work because it would compromise security.

Comment: Can you expand a bit on the security? Can you give a specific example of something prevented that an alternative will allow? I've not actually seen security as a reason for the ArrayBuffer, and indeed the asm.js spec at http://asmjs.org/spec/latest/ doesn't seem to mention security, but does mention efficiency and optimization.

Comment: Security is implied by the JavaScript virtual machine's model, which asm.js has to follow since it's just a subset of JavaScript. The virtual machine wants to control its entire address space to be able to GC objects as well as for security. The security aspect is mainly based on not allowing developers to store to other parts of the process' address space, e.g. the VM itself, which would be trivial to exploit. For ArrayBuffers its a bit more subtle since the VM could just use a bounds check. It's more of an information / ASLR leak in that case.